# Extract data from ConvexHullMesh

Tags: regions, mesh

I have a `ConvexHullMesh` and want to extract the bounding points.

I am familiar with using `Cases` to extract data from plots but the technique returns nothing from the mesh region.

Here is a simple example.

```
     pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}};
     plot = ListLinePlot[pts]
     Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x__], Infinity]
```

This returns the line in the plot, as expected.

```
    {Line[{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}, {2., 0.}, {3., 2.}}]}
```

But when I try to do the same with a `ConvexHullMesh`, the result is an empty list, even though `FullForm` clearly shows there is a `Line[__]` in the expression.

```
    chm=ConvexHullMesh[pts];
    chm//FullForm
    Cases[Normal@chm, Line[x__], Infinity]
```

I also notice that `Apply[f,chm]` has no effect on the mesh; the head does not change.

So what can I do?

Comment: Just use `MeshCoordinates[chm]` to get the points. If you want the boundary `RegionBoundary[chm]`.  You can get the lines with `MeshPrimitives[RegionBoundary[chm], 1]` (or in 3D the faces with `MeshPrimitives[RegionBoundary[chm], 2]`)