# Finding the smallest bounding simplex

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nearest

I would like to find the subset of points from a set of d-dimensional points that defines the smallest bounding simplex around a given point.  For example, given a set of 3-dimensional points S1 and another point x1, I am looking for the subset of S1 that form the bounding 3-polytope around x1 with the smallest volume.
I am thinking of the following:

1. Compute `nn = Nearest[s->{"Index", "Distance", "Element"}, p, d+1]`
2. Check if the given point p is inside the returned simplex
   `RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[nn[[1, All, 3]]], p]` of the returned points).
3. If yes, return the points, indices and distances.
4. If no, back to step 1 with d+1 neighbors, then evaluate step 2 for all of `Subsets[nn[[1, All, 3]]], {d}]`.
5. If all d-simplices are evaluated and none of them enclose p, start over with d+1 simplices.

I would be glad if someone could improve on this.

Comment: `ConvexHullMesh[{pt1,pt2, ...}]`

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but `ConvexHullMesh[]` only gives me the bounding simplex of the given points, but I need something like this: `Nearest[{p1,p2,p3,p4}, {p5}, n + 1]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the smallest bounding simplex"? Please give the definition and an example and your attempts.

Comment: After generating the `MeshCoordinates@ConvexHullMesh[{pt1, pt2, pt3, ...}]` should give you the bounding points that define the convex hull mesh. See also, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225381/extract-data-from-convexhullmesh

Comment: Given a set of 3-dimensional points S1 and another point x1, I am looking for the subset of S1 that form the smallest bounding 3-polytope around x1.

Comment: I repeat the question: what do you mean by the smallest one? with the smallest volume/area/diameter/something else?

Comment: @user64494 I mean volume.

Comment: Your question would benefit from some code and a graphic to clarify your objective.

Comment: Sounds NP-hard. Note that the nearest points need not yield the smallest volume polytope. How many points do you have in $S_1$?

Comment: `Subsets[points,{4}]` will give you every tetrahedron. Then Google will let you find a simple function that will tell you whether your point is inside a tetrahedron given by the four verticies. Then Google will let you find a simple function that will tell you the volume of a tetrahedron given by four verticies. Then Sort, or other related functions, will let you select the tetrahedron of the smallest volume. Does that give you a plan?

Comment: @A.G. It is NP-hard, but I only have a few hundred points.

Comment: @Bill Thanks, it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question, this can be done as follows.
We create a a random point set in four dimensions and choose all its triples.

```
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];
subsets = Subsets[points, {3}];
```

Let `p` be a given point presented as a list of one element.

```
p = {{2, 1, -3}};
```

Now we create a list of volumes of all the simplexes around `p`

```
t = Table[RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[
RegionMember[Simplex[Union[p, subsets[[j]]]], {x, y, z}], {x, y, 
 z}]], {j, 1, 50}];
```

In the end

```
Min[t]
```

> `0.00325795`

```
FirstPosition[t, Min[t]]
```

> `{19}`

It is clear how to modify the above in other dimensions greater than or equal to three.

Edit. Reduction of the previous version of the above code to three dimensions.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you very much.

Comment: All the pleasure is mine.

Comment: It should be `(j,1,Binomial[50,3]}` instead of `{j, 1, 50}` in the above.